# Wrong screen showing after start with ScreenManager

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to code a simple quiz game. There're supposed to be multiple screens, the first screen (LoginWindow) being a simple login form. After the login and confirmation of the right name and password being entered the second screen (GameWindow) is supposed to show up, but it doesn't. Right from the start the second screen is being loaded.
I'm sure I am missing something super simple and basic but I just don't get it.

.py file:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
import hashlib

Window.size = (512, 512)

user_hash = ""
pass_hash = ""

super_user = "9279F4A7C1C145D5AE930FDA23EF386168F6720B4E0F0D3DEE383C5AD8535737"
super_pass = "EE22032527082315A747781829EF1F9195F6AEAC09C0D52DE06EBF9D8C463918"


# Define screens
class LoginWindow(Screen):

    name = ObjectProperty(None)
    passw = ObjectProperty(None)

    def press(self):
        user_hash = hashlib.sha256(self.name.text.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest().upper()
        pass_hash = hashlib.sha256(self.passw.text.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest().upper()
        if (user_hash == super_user) and (pass_hash == super_pass):
            print("Das hat geklappt!")
            WindowManager.current = 'game'
        else:
            print("Du kummst hier net rein!")


class GameWindow(Screen):
    pass


class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


kv = Builder.load_file('box_multiscreen.kv')


class Affenquiz(App):

    def build(self):
        Window.clearcolor = (0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 1)
        WindowManager = ScreenManager()
        WindowManager.add_widget(LoginWindow(name='login'))
        WindowManager.add_widget(GameWindow(name='game'))
        WindowManager.current = 'login'

        return kv


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Affenquiz().run()
```

.kv file:

```
WindowManager:
    LoginWindow:
        name: "login"
    GameWindow:
        name: "game"

<LoginWindow>:

    name:name
    passw:passw

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        size: root.width, root.height

        spacing: 20
        padding: 20

        canvas.before:
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
                source: 'monkey.png'

        AnchorLayout:
            anchor_y: 'top'
            BoxLayout:
                orientation: "horizontal"
                size_hint: (1, None)
                height: 50

                Label:
                    text: "Der Quizfelsen"
                    font_size: 50

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            size_hint: (1, None)
            height: 50

            Label:
                text: "Benutzer:"
            TextInput:
                id: name
                multiline:False
                background_color: (241/255.0,241/255.0,241/255.0,0.9)

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            size_hint: (1, None)
            height: 50

            Label:
                text: "Passwort:"
            TextInput:
                id: passw
                multiline:False
                background_color: (241/255.0,241/255.0,241/255.0,0.9)

        RoundedButton:
            text: "Login"
            pos_hint: {'center_x': .5}
            size_hint: (1, None)
            height: 50
            on_press: root.press()

<GameWindow>:
    Label:
        text: "Der Quizfelsen"
        font_size: 50

<Label>
    font_size: 32
    background_normal: ''
    background_color: (0.9,0.9,0.9,0)
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: self.background_color
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
    color: (184/255.0,70/255.0,35/255.0,1)
    bold: True
    outline_color: (1,1,1,1)
    outline_width: 2

<RoundedButton@Button>
    background_color: (0,0,0,0)
    background_normal: ''
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (184/255.0,70/255.0,35/255.0,0.9)
        RoundedRectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
            radius: [25]
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Try changing the property named `name = ObjectProperty(None)` of screen `LoginWindow` with something like `user_name = ObjectProperty(None)` (most likely it overrides the default attr. `name` of `Screen`).

Comment: Well ... that's a little bit embarrassing. That was the problem indeed. I most likely never wouldv'e thought about that. Thanks a lot.